# Best way to populate e-mail body from uitableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, core-data, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Ok let me try to make it a better question.

I have a tableViewController in my app containing some info that the user would like to email someone with that data from the tableview.

I could retain an array with that information.

The tough part of the question is how do i populate the body of the message with the data from my tableview using objective-c language ?

Do I have to make a huge string containing all the html code ? Or is there a better/easier way around it ? Even if it is a simple looking table just so the client will send that out to someone.

I guess any solution/advice could be a great waypoint for me to know how should i work with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks just like"? Do you want something that is literally like a screenshot of the table view? Or you want to lay out your items in rows?

Comment: @quixoto : A screenshot wouldn't work because it wouldn't capture the items down further where you scroll so I want to layout my items. Any idea of how to format ? I could just throw an array there but it would look ugly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I freaking nailed it !
If you guys ever want to compose an email having the data from your UITableViewController
here's how i made it. Just remember to import your data header file...

```
#import Recipe.h //in the implementation file
#import Ingredients.h //in the implementation file
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h> // this line gotta be in the header file

-(IBAction)sendmail{
MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *recipeTitle = @"<h5>Recipe name: ";
recipeTitle = [recipeTitle stringByAppendingFormat:recipe.name];
recipeTitle = [recipeTitle stringByAppendingFormat:@"</h5>"];

NSString *ingredientAmount = @"";
NSString *ingredientAisle = @"";
NSString *ingredientTitle = @"";

NSString *tableFirstLine = @"<table width='300' border='1'><tr><td>Ingredient</td><td>Amount</td><td>Aisle</td></tr>";
NSString *increments = @"";
increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:recipeTitle];
increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:tableFirstLine];
int i;

for (i=0; i < [ingredients count]; i++) {
    Ingredient *ingredient = [ingredients objectAtIndex:i];
    ingredientTitle = ingredient.name;
    ingredientAmount = ingredient.amount;
    ingredientAisle = ingredient.aisle;

    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr><td>"];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:ingredientTitle];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td><td>"];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:ingredientAmount];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td><td>"];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:ingredientAisle];
    increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:@"</td></tr>"];
    if (i == [ingredients count]) {
        //IF THIS IS THE LAST INGREDIENT, CLOSE THE TABLE
        increments = [increments stringByAppendingFormat:@"</table>"];
    }
}

NSLog(@"CODE:: %@", increments);

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123@abc.com", nil]];
    [composer setSubject:@"subject here"];
    [composer setMessageBody:increments isHTML:YES];
    [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    [composer release];
}else {
    [composer release];
    }
}
```

This one was a huge step for me and it is actually very useful if you want to create interesting (basic) tools in your app.
Thanks to everyone in this quintessential website for objective-c programmers.

Andthis is the result you get. Simple but a good way to start.

[image]

Comment: As promised. Here's the screenshot. Very simple table but the basics are all here.